# Split large XML to smaller chunks by node count using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement where we are getting a large XML file and I need to transform on small chunks

below is the XML sample with 4 records, I have to transform the XML so I am able to group them in chunks of 2.

```
<!-- Original XML-->
<EmpDetails>
    <Records>
        <EmpID>1</EmpID>
        <Age>20</Age>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <EmpID>2</EmpID>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <EmpID>3</EmpID>
        <Age>22</Age>
    </Records>
    <Records>
        <EmpID>4</EmpID>
        <Age>23</Age>
    </Records>
</EmpDetails>


<!-- Expected XML-->
<EmpDetails>
    <Split>
        <Records>
            <EmpID>1</EmpID>
            <Age>20</Age>
        </Records>
        <Records>
            <EmpID>2</EmpID>
            <Age>21</Age>
        </Records>
    </Split>
    <Split>
        <Records>
            <EmpID>3</EmpID>
            <Age>22</Age>
        </Records>
        <Records>
            <EmpID>4</EmpID>
            <Age>23</Age>
        </Records>
    </Split>
</EmpDetails>
```

I tried few things including below without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <EmpDetails>
      <xsl:for-each select="/EmpDetails/Records">
        <Split>
          <Records>
            <EmpID>
              <xsl:value-of select="EmpID"/>
            </EmpID>
            <Age>
              <xsl:value-of select="Age"/>
            </Age>
          </Records>
        </Split>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </EmpDetails>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks
Yatan

Comment: Please always say which XSLT version you are using. Grouping becomes trivial in XSLT 2.0 using the `xsl:for-each-group` construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> group them in chunks of 2.

This could be done simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/EmpDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Records[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <Split>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Records[1]"/>
            </Split>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To divide the records into groups of 200, you can do:

```
    ...
        <xsl:for-each select="Records[position() mod 200 = 1]">
            <Split>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Records[position() &lt; 200]"/>
            </Split>
        </xsl:for-each>
    ...
```

In **XSLT 2.0** you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/EmpDetails">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Records" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv 200">
            <Split>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </Split>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I can use both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, can you tell me how we can group 200 records, I believe some magic here, <xsl:for-each select="Records[position() mod 2 = 1]"> however not sure.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to divide 200 records into groups of 2 each? Or N records into groups of 200 each?.

Comment: N records into groups of 200 each

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Answer (score -2):

use this code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records[position() mod 2 = 0]">
```

instead of this

```
<xsl:for-each select="Records[position() mod 2 = 1]">
```

Comment: Why would this be a good thing??