# XSLT concat same elements by count (concat to new element for every 5 same elements)

Tags: xml, xslt, concatenation

Please help me to provide XSLT code,
My XML consists of multiple elements of same name  and I am trying to concatenate every 5 same elements into a new element.
My XML looks like below:

My XML consists of multiple elements of same name  and I am trying to concatenate every 5 same elements into a new element.
My XML looks like below:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Model_No>A321</Model_No>
        <Model_Name>ABC</Model_Name>
        <Collection/>
        <Collection merge="Y">A</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">B</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">C</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">D</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">E</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">F</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">G</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">H</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">I</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">J</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">K</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">L</Collection>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Model_No>B432</Model_No>
        <Model_Name>XYZ</Model_Name>
        <Collection/>
        <Collection merge="Y">Z</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">Y</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">X</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">V</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">U</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">T</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">S</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">R</Collection>
        <Collection merge="Y">Q</Collection>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I am expecting the results as follows:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Model_No>A321</Model_No>
        <Model_Name>ABC</Model_Name>
        <Collection>ABCDE</Collection>
        <Collection>FGHIJ</Collection>
        <Collection>KL</Collection>
       </Product>
    <Product>
        <Model_No>B432</Model_No>
        <Model_Name>XYZ</Model_Name>
        <Collection>ZYXVU</Collection>
        <Collection>TSRQ</Collection>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

My XSLT code is as follows, please help me get this solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="initial-collections" 
          match="Collection[@merge = 'Y']" 
            use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Collection[not(@merge = 'Y')][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product/Collection[not(@merge = 'Y')]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
               select="node() | key('initial-collections', generate-id())/node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Product/Collection[@merge = 'Y']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Appreciate your help. Many Thanks.

- Raj

Comment: Your stylesheet declares `version="3.0` yet you attempt  to use Muenchian grouping which is only required in XSLT 1.0 and - more importantly - will not help here. If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher,  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607158/3016153.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this XSLT 2.0 solution tested with Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7. I have updated the answer following Michaels excellent suggestion, cf. below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Product">
    <Product>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Model_No | Model_Name"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="Collection[@merge = 'Y'][position() mod 5 = 1]">
        <Collection>
          <xsl:value-of select=". | following-sibling::Collection[@merge = 'Y'][position() &lt; 5]"
            separator=""/>
        </Collection>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Product>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why not simply: `<xsl:value-of select=".|following-sibling::Collection[@merge='Y'][position() lt 5]" separator=""/>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas. It perfectly worked with my scenario. Appreciate your time and help.