# XML to XSLT - Question - Repeating XML Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have data that comes in from the XML like this....

```
   <DetailLine><FormField><Name>Vendor Item</Name> 
   <DisplayValue>0201029</DisplayValue><Value /><Value2 /> 
   </FormField><FormField><Name>Item Description</Name> 
   <DisplayValue>BOX JUNCTION HF AHC5111 10X10X</DisplayValue> 
   <Value>BOX JUNCTION HF AHC5111 10X10X</Value><Value2 />
    <DetailLine><FormField><Name>Vendor Item</Name> 
   <DisplayValue>0201040</DisplayValue><Value /><Value2 /> 
   </FormField><FormField><Name>Item Description</Name> 
   <DisplayValue>BOX JUNCTION HF A201608LP 20 X</DisplayValue> 
   <Value>BOX JUNCTION HF A201608LP 20 X</Value><Value2 />
```

I can code it in the XSLT like this, and as long as I know exactly how many lines I have, it works....

```
<xsl:for-each 
  select="GeneratedDocument/Detail/DetailLine[10]/FormField">
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="DisplayValue"/>
</td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I want it to be smarter and just say for each detail line, put 10 display values and go to the next row.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

I want to return all the display values into each column and create a new row for each new detail line.

Each detail line has fixed 10 display values.

Sorry for all edits.  New here.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Did you mean something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607158/3016153?

Comment: Updated above.  Is it clear now?  Sorry, new user to stackflow here.

Comment: The XSLT code with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="DisplayValue"/>`  selects elements named `DisplayValue` which are not present in the sample input data you have added. So that sample data doesn't make it clear what your XSLT code tries to do or fails to do as the data has mostly different elements from the ones selected in XPath expressions in the XSLT.

Comment: Clarified the xml inbound.  Sorry, like i said, new here.